# Python parsing and cleaning up

Tags: python

I am running a program that produced the following output strings stored into a list:

```
['41.6640', '-91.5447\n', '41.6640', '-91.5447\n', '41.6640', '-91.5447\n', '41.6640', '-91.5447\n', '41.6640', '-91.5447\n']
```

I need a simple code to remove the `\n` from any strings it is in.  Seems like it should be really straightforward, but every time i get errors or end up deleting the whole string.

Comment: Check out the strip method on strings

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple list comprehension:

```
myList = [i.rstrip() for i in myList]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [13]: a = ['41.6640', '-91.5447\n', '41.6640', '-91.5447\n', '41.6640', '-91.5447\n', '41.6640', '-91.5447\n', '41.6640', '-91.5447\n']

In [14]: map(str.rstrip, a) 
Out[14]: 
['41.6640',
 '-91.5447',
 '41.6640',
 '-91.5447',
 '41.6640',
 '-91.5447',
 '41.6640',
 '-91.5447',
 '41.6640',
 '-91.5447']

In [15]: map(float, a) # To convert to float, you don't need rstrip
Out[15]: 
[41.664,
 -91.5447,
 41.664,
 -91.5447,
 41.664,
 -91.5447,
 41.664,
 -91.5447,
 41.664,
 -91.5447]
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop trough your elements and check if "\n" is there, then strap it like this:

```
for n in my_list:
   if "\\n" in n:
      n = n[0:len(n) - 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

map applies a function on every element in an iterable and returns it as a new list. In this case, you can use `str.strip` to remove whitespace on both ends of the strings.

```
myList = ['41.6640', '-91.5447\n', '41.6640', '-91.5447\n', '41.6640', '-91.5447\n', '41.6640', '-91.5447\n', '41.6640', '-91.5447\n']
myList = map(str.strip, myList)
```